# Removal of vertical HoughLines/Detection of Horizontal HoughLines only

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I wish to ask if there is a method to detect only the nearly horizontal Hough Lines or ignoring those nearly vertical Hough Lines? My code for the HoughLine now is as shown:

```
HoughLinesP(imagec, lines, 80, CV_PI/2, CV_THRESH_OTSU|CV_THRESH_BINARY, 25, 7);
for(size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
    {
      Vec4i l = lines[i];
      line(imagec, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(255,255,255), 8, 8);
      line(imagelines, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(255,255,255), 8, 8); //draw on black image as well
    }
```

However in the image, I am seeking only to detect horizontal lines, or at least near horizontal lines like by 2 to 4 cm. I am using `CV_PI/2` for the theta parameter in the HoughLineP, hence the vertical lines/ near vertical lines are detected too.

Any suggestions, code samples, etc will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove  vertical line

- First find the angle for each line using the equation

  `double Angle = atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180.0 / CV_PI;`
- Just ignore the line which has angle 90 degree(vertical line).

Done !.

Comment: Thanks, Do you know how to get the values of y2,y1,x2,x1 from a vector? I am using "vector<Vec4i> lines;" for my lines, hence I can't use CvPoint to get those, and that is the only way I know. Thanks.

Comment: Solved it. I used atan instead of atan2. Thanks once again(:

Comment: Just to add, for python-opencv users, it would be `np.arctan2`

Answer (score 9):

Python version

```
import numpy as np
angle = np.arctan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180. / np.pi
```